# How can i go back from Native ViewController to react native page in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I have react native page through which I am able to redirect Native ViewController but I am not able to get back from Native ViewController to React-Native page on back button click. I have added logs on back press and getting logs in console but ViewController is not getting dismissed.

```
    func goToNativeView() { 
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) 
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePageInner") 
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }

- (IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender { 
NSLog(@"BACKBUTTONPRESSED"); 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: post some code bro

Comment: //this function will be called from the RCTBridge 
    func goToNativeView() {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePageInner")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }


//native viewcontroller
- (IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"BACKBUTTONPRESSED");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: `func goToNativeView() {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePageInner")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }`

Comment: `- (IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"BACKBUTTONPRESSED");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
`

Comment: you are not using navigation controller bro thats why you cant go back

Comment: @DevilDecoder initially i used Navigation controller but it overlaps my existing view and back button on it, that's why i removed it from code.

Comment: if it is overlapping then you can hide it but with out navigation controller going back and forth is not possible except changing rootViewControllers

Comment: @DevilDecoder self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let navigate = UINavigationController()

        
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePageInner")
        
        navigate.pushViewController(initialViewController, animated: false)

        
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigate

Comment: @DevilDecoder i have added my ViewController in NavigationViewController but still not working

Comment: you are not initialising you vc as root view of you navigation controller use let navigate = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewController) and then assign it to window root view controller

Comment: self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePageInner")
        
        let navigate = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewController)
        
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigate
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: @DevilDecoder Tried this way, but still not working